# Change git configuration username and email permanently

Tags: github, git-commit, git-config, git

I have changed the username and email in git config via

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/

When I check the config file with git config --global user.name or email it is showing the correct email and username.

The commits in my project are linked to my github account while in the home page of github it is shown as previous_user pushed to master.

Why are commits linked to me while the pushes are linked to previous user.

I will be really very thankful if someone helps.

Comment: You need to change the history of your commits. Search for `git filter-branch`

Comment: Did yuo push those commits linked to you? Changing the config won't change anything for previous existing commits.

Comment: Commits(for new or old branch) done after changing the username and email are linked to me while pushes(for both old and new) are same. Moreover if I setup a new project or anything new as generating ssh keys I get the message in terminal as previous user. How do I remove that previous user from my system so that everything done related to github from my system should be related to my account.